# Gatling Conditional on Response Body

Tags: scala, gatling

I am currently using Gatling and I have a scenario whereby I perform a number of GET requests and depending on the body of the responses I would like to perform a different scenario.

I have this at the moment that doesn't appear to work as expected -

```
  val repeatSpin = scenario("repeatScenario1").repeat(10) {
    exec(
      scenario1
    )
    .doIf(bodyString => bodyString.equals("<SwitchEvent/>")){
      exec(scenario2)
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got the [`.doIf` parameters wrong](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/general/scenario.html#doif) - it either takes a key in the session and the value you expect, like:

```
.doIf("${bodyString}", "<SwitchEvent/>") { myChain }
```

Or, an `Expression[Boolean]` - the argument you get is the [`session`](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/index.html); to get values out of a session you do [something like](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/session_api.html#getting-attributes) `session("bodyString").as[String]`. So, passing a function to the `doIf` could look like

```
.doIf(session => session("bodyString").as[String].equals("<SwitchEvent/>")) { myChain }
```